# Redirect all subfolder's home to index using 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

My website structure is like

Main (Root directory)

```
index.php
home.php
```

Sub-folder

```
index.php
home.php
```

There are many sub-folder under root directory.

I am able to redirect main root home page to index by using following code

```
Redirect 301 /home /
Redirect 301 /home.php /
```

But, I want to redirect all sub-folder's home to it's own index page. How can I do ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please show more examples of the redirections you want to implement.  For example, what should the result be if someone accesses `/subdir2/index.php`?

Comment: Thanks for response, Mainly, there are two php file in public_html folder. one is index.php and another is home.php. if user visit **http://www.krishisansar.com/home** it redirects to **http://www.krishisansar.com**. Like this I want to redirect subfolder home to it's own index. For example public_html has news, article and other sub-directory with home and index page. If visitor visit **http://www.krishisansar.com/news/home**, it will be able to redirects **http://www.krishisansar.com/news/**. All sub-directories have home and index page. how to redirect all home page to index ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?home/?$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

This routes `/news/home` to `/news/index.php` OR `/home` to `/index.php`

Comment: Yeah! that worked! Thank you!  one more question. when visiting root url like **www.krishisansar.com/home.php** or **www.krishisansar.com/index.php** it redirects and only shows **www.krishisansar.com**. How to apply this method to all sub-directory. I mean when visiting subdirectory like **www.krishisansar.com/news/home.php**, **www.krishisansar.com/article/home.php** it redirects own index page, it's ok. But in url it shows **www.krishisansar.com/article/home.php**. I want to show only **www.krishisansar.com/article/**.

Comment: It would be better if you create a new question with these additional requirements since it will require some additional rule not related with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a server, use the 'dot' to start at the root.

./home/

Comment: Thanks for response, Mainly, there are two php file in public_html folder. one is index.php and another is home.php. if user visit **http://www.krishisansar.com/home** it redirects to **http://www.krishisansar.com**. Like this I want to redirect subfolder home to it's own index. For example public_html has news, article and other sub-directory with home and index page. If visitor visit **http://www.krishisansar.com/news/home**, it will be able to redirects **http://www.krishisansar.com/news/**. All sub-directories have home and index page. how to redirect all home page to index ? –